# Make a fixed div scroll to top of another div?

Tags: jquery, offset, scrolltop

I have some code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maYHb/43/).

Let me explain it more clearly to you:

I want the `#top_bar` always scroll to and stay exactly on top of the div that ID is the href value of a hyperlink when user click on it (in other hand, the bottom border of `#top_bar` is near by the top border if destination div).

Let's say that you click on DIV4 link, the `#top_bar` will be fixed at top of screen, and the window will scroll to `#DIV4`, but the `#top_bar` will cover some content of `#DIV4` too.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your jsfiddle is not running as you have wrapped the code in your document head. I have rectified it. you can check the js updated at http://jsfiddle.net/maYHb/44/

Now coming back to your query. You have animated scroll the html and body tag. And you want the div to show the number (ie set the exact top below the menu bar and not behind it).
You havent consider the menu height and the margins you have given these elements. You have take that into consideration too. Please check the above fiddle. I have added this code.

```
   var dest_pos = $(anchor).offset().top-38-40; // 38px for menu div height and 40 px for margin. 
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: dest_pos}, 1000);
```

Please adjust the css of it with common margins and structure and you will get the desired output. Till then I would try to improve the css as well.

Also rather than giving animate scroll to the body. Give it to the div wrapper.